Best way to find and click this identical span element with Selenium Webdriver + Python?
The highlighted element is the one I'm trying to select:

I have tried many different ways to select this element including text, xpath, id, etc. Having trouble locating it entirely.
It is in a div class with identical span elements surrounding it, the only personal identifier being the text. In the example it is "14" and it is sequential so the next is "15" and so on. Is there a way to select the 'nth' element within this div as a workaround?
datepick = driver.find_element(By.ID, ...)

datepick = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, ...)

etc. no luck.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

There's an :nth-child(N) CSS Selector, which may come in handy for your situation.
Here's a selector you can try using with that:
"div.main-calendar-days span:nth-child(14) span"
Here's code for clicking it:
selector = "div.main_calendar_days span:nth-child(14) span"
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, selector).click()

